# Check if an image already exists in the filesystem under a different name

Tags: linux, filesystems

I've been given a suitcase full of old data-cds full of images which have to be saved. However, it is quite possible that a lot of these images are already saved in the filesystem, but i don't know where (the system already contains about 170000 pictures) and they could be saved under a different name. So is there a way to easily check if an image that contains this binary data (exif may differ because I don't know how the pictures have been saved earlier, the cds are up to 20 years old) already exists in a file system?

I am using Arch Linux. Also open to write a bit of code if needed, but if so it should be code that is fast because it would have to run quite a few times. Preferably solution working from the cmd-line.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, if clarification is needed I'm happy to reply to comments. Please let me know if i forgot any important information, I'm new here.

Edit:
I could maybe narrow the amount of files to check down from 170000 to maybe 20000-30000 because there are some folders which are guaranteed to not contain the wanted images. If this is of any help, it would be possible.

Comment: What will happen if you have the same image, but one copy is with EXIF, another is w/o? What will happen if difference between two image is just a pixel? What if you have the same image in different formats? What if you have same image (JPEG, TIFF for example) with different level of compression?

Comment: These will probably be edge cases, in which it would not matter if the picture gets saved although it is already there. The format problem on the other hand is something I have to think about, but for now I'd say the most realistic case is that the image has already been copied from this cd to the system a few years back, hence the binary data of the image should be the very same if that has happened

Comment: So are you OK if you find the files with same content?

Comment: Well I try to avoid copying files that already exist but if a few slip through it won't be the end of the world

Answer (score 1):

Something like can check for existing files and generate `sha1`:

```
 find <path to image root> -type f -exec sha1sum {} \; 2>/dev/null|awk '{gsub(/^.*\//,"",$2); print $1,$2}' >/tmp/sums1
```

The above command `find` files starting from defined directory and exec `sha1sum` for each finding. The STDERR is redirected to `/dev/null` to avoid messages like "you do not have rights....". The the output is redirected to `awk` where `gsub` substitute from start to slash (`/`). This is to remove the path from the output of `find` and keep only filename. Otherwise you will have the path and second execution of `sha1sum` may not find the files in the path. The `awk` print token 1 and 2. And there is redirection to some file.

then you go to the CD directory and with

```
sha1sum -c /tmp/sums1 2>/dev/null|grep -v "OK$"
```

check if there is file with same checksum as existing. This will search for images and sums only in current directory you are.

Also you can generate checksums on both image locations and CD, merge checksum files, sort and strip non equivalent consecutive records.

Comment: Thanks very much, I'll try that asap. If you've got time, could you explain the first command a bit? I'd like to understand what is happening so i don't have to ask next time

Comment: Thanks again very much! The checksums are being calculated right now

Comment: Something seems to be not working. The sums-file shows a checksum and the name of the corrosponding file. But when i execute the second command in the cd directory, it displays for every line in the sums file: Failed to open or read <filename> and file or directory not found. The last output is 195000 listed files could not be read and 713 calculated checksums do NOT fit. Any idea on how to make it work?

Comment: Let me edit the answer

Comment: Probably works better (more efficiently) with a `-size` filter?

Comment: @TomYan, I do not use `find` in second part. So `-size` make no sense for me

Comment: Never mind. I misread the the question as finding the duplicate of a specific (filesystem image) file. However, I don't think `-c` of `sha1sum` actually "`search`" with each sum, but merely hash the file/path in the record under the current working directly anyway? (note `and they could be saved under a different name`)

Answer (score 0):

So, I finally made it work. Piggybacking on the other answer here. The first command in that answer generates the desired file containing all the checksums of all the files that are already in the filesystem. But the second command still returns no usable output, which is why i wrote a bash script to do that job for me. There is probably a way to do this more elegant, but this worked for me.

Thanks again

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s globstar
for filename in **/*; do
    if [ -f "$filename" ]; then
        calculated_checksum=$(sha1sum -- "$filename" | awk '{print $1}')
        if ! grep -q "$calculated_checksum" /tmp/sums1; then
            echo "$filename has to be copied" 
        else
            echo "Match: $filename"
        fi
    fi
done
```

Comment: This will only detect files that are bit-to-bit identical. It will miss all identical images saved in different formats.

Comment: Yes, but that is the same problem in the other answer and also negligible for my usecase